# Should you let users edit other people's answer to encourage downvoting?

Tags: discussion, edits

I came across an accepted answer that was subsequently edited by an unrelated party with the comment "This is not 100% correct - downvote!"  (paraphrased)

The editor left no other comment (that I would have thought is the accepted result) nor attempted to actually correct the answer (that would have been helpful).

But what appears necessary and unhelpful is the "downvote" encouragement.

Is it appropriate to re-edit this answer to remove the "downvote" encouragement, even though it was previously approved by others?

Or should we just flag to moderators? Or accept it?

Edit:

The link to the question has been removed to prevent retaliation down-voting (which is fair enough). For those now reading this question, the edit that this relates to was

> Edit (*Name removed - user signed the post here*), 2014-08-18): Attention, none of the "ISO formats" are valid ISO format output. ISO 8601 is not aware of any three letter time zime codes but only offsets to UTC. Downvote!

Comment: The problem is not about the suggested edit. The problem is with the later revision which adds the comment telling people to downvote.

Comment: What does the suggested edit introduce that you think is encouraging down votes?

Comment: Sorry - I provided the incorrect edit link - updated question. The edit reads "Edit (Michael-O, 2014-08-18): Attention, none of the "ISO formats" are valid ISO format output. ISO 8601 is not aware of any three letter time zime codes but only offsets to UTC. Downvote!"

Comment: I rolled back that edit. That was way out of line, it should've been a comment instead.

Comment: Jeez. That needs to become a review-queue audit question. It's awful.

Comment: A user with around 4k reputation (at the point of editing) did that? This is very very sad. Is it possible that mods can revoke the 2k edit right?

Comment: @Tom: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: This user seems to be "signing" edits to their own questions too ([e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23116610/472495)). I don't think I've seen that before!

Comment: @Tom Moderators can impose a temporary edit ban.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Even if the user has edit privilige?

Comment: @Deduplicator The [tag:edit-ban] tag wiki seems to imply that, yes.

Comment: How evil is it of me to have chuckled at the comment by the offending user, who received retaliatory downvotes.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

> *Should you let users edit other people's answer to encourage downvoting?*

No.

To elaborate, an answer is an answer. It is not for adding unrelated opinions (FWIW, I'm not *judging* the merit, whatsoever of the opinion). There is a dedicated comment section to show agree/disagreement and suggest/ propose changes, if any.

As it is written, the edit should have come as a comment. If the mistake is having reasonable impact, maybe a downvote, too and if possible, edit to improve.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking; and the fact Cerebus immediately rolled back that edit confirmed I should have just done it! Thanks.

Comment: Editing the answer to completely change the *content*, due to it being completely wrong, is entirely inappropriate.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content, not to change it entirely from what they think the answer is to what you think the answer is.

Comment: @Servy Agree. That is why I used _improve_, not _correct_. An altogether wrong answer is wrong, and warrants a downvote and comment for OP to correct it, not eligible for edit to _improve_. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Improving the presentation of content that is completely wrong is not productive.  The actual content would need to be changed so that it's just not wrong, and that's not an appropriate edit.  Additionally, just adding entirely new content is *also* wrong.  The actual answer itself shouldn't be changed *at all* in an edit; the edits should only be improving how the original author's answer is presented.  Clearly the problem with the answer in question is not its presentation.

Comment: @Servy I did not get you clearly sir. I agree, improving the format by adding backticks to an altogether wrong answer does not add any value, but when you say _"adding entirely new content is also wrong."_, I'm confused. I've seen, with time,  many answers getting edited to add the updated content into it, and that is encouraged, to keep the answer updated (correct me if I'm wrong). Those __are__ more than improvement considering the fact that new content (of course, related and relevant content) is actually getting added into it. How to consider those cases then?

Comment: @Servy However, in regard to _this_ question, the edit itself __should have been__ a comment, so the case of _improvement_ to that _invalid_ addition does not come into picture itself. :)

Comment: If you have a alternate way of solving the problem that you think is better than the existing answers, you should be adding a new answer, not editing an existing answer.  And if you feel that editing the answer isn't correct in this case then you shouldn't say in your answer here that editing the answer is an appropriate option.

Comment: @Servy I'm still confused sir (i'm not a native english speaker, please bear with me). All I mentioned that the edit done by the "third-party" to the original answer in the original (targeted) question was wrong and should have been a comment. In general, the mistakes (mainly typos), like using `=` in place of `==` can be corrected through edit, though they change the meaning, right? After all, reading the description with the answer can help us identify this kind of typos which can be edited to improve. Changing a "yes" to "no" is absolutely a no-go. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh There you're maintaining the original author's intent.  They intended to have an `==` and it was just a typo, so you can change it.  If they made it clear that they really want it to be a `=` and not a `==` then no, it wouldn't be appropriate to change it.

Answer (score 54):

That user appears to have made quite a few edits like this.

I rolled back all of those that simply said things like *"This doesn't work"*, and removed lines where his edit was genuine, but where he also added the edit reason *in* the post.

I also flagged one of the posts for a moderator to have a look at.

Comment: Thanks. SO can be daunting enough without those users!

Comment: I should have been able to assume that. :-)

Comment: I flag 2 posts in th' morning, I flag 2 posts at night. I flag 2 posts that time of day, and then I feel allright :D I flag 2 posts when I am bored, and flag 2 posts when not. I flag 2 posts before I flag 2 posts, and then I flag 2 more!

Comment: (Yet my flag count is shamefully low)

Comment: That’s pretty unflagging flagging.

Comment: I should add that rhyme to my profile, I flag too much..

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion or just change your name to "Infinite Flagging".